# Nullable<Nullable> or Optional<Nullable> in C#

Tags: c#, nullable, option-type

Since the first comment on this question will probably be why and the why is what likely makes this not a duplicate question: I have a value type variable (of type decimal if that matters) that has three valid states: `has value | null | unspecified`. It would be best to represent all three of these states without a custom class. Also, `0.0m` and any other decimal value are valid. Unfortunately, `Nullable<Nullable<decimal>>` is not valid in C#. What is the best way to do this?

UPDATE:

Eric's comments below caused me to think about this a bit differently. Coming at the question above as a software architect, the core philosophical question is how to handle the case where `null` can represent multiple meanings. The particular example that motivated this question is:

In our system, there are tables with product offerings (price, minimum order quantity, some user defined values, etc). The tables have hierarchy. In order to compute the offer values in the child table the "parent offers" need to be considered. The idea is for `null` to represent the case where a constraint has been removed and `null(null)` (for lack of a better syntax) to imply no change to the parent value.

Now, granted, C# is used (abused?) in a strictly functional manner by us, consequence being that needs are sometimes orthogonal to C#'s purpose. Hopefully the next version of C# has discriminated unions which would be perfect for this.

Comment: Using a custom class.

Comment: Yeah, that hope was that I missed something obvious.

Comment: How is "unspecified" different from "null"?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn say you have a variable `x` of type `string`.  It is currently `null`.  The OP would like to know if it was set to null or if it simply defaulted that way.  It's a tri-state variable like `Nullable<bool>`, but instead of `false` being the default value, it's `null` here.

Comment: IF @Amy's analysis is the reason this is needed, and you want to avoid a custom class, you could define a dependent read only property on the same object that houses the decimal? property that indicates if the value was set to null rather than being null by default.

Comment: I would strongly push back on this design. Nullable already has the semantics of "unspecified". The reason we made nullable-of-nullable illegal was to prevent representation of the notion that there are "hierarchies" of unspecified-ness. If you do need to go down this route then I suggest that you crisp up what "null" means distinct from "unspecified".  For example, it would be more clear to have states "unknown", "unspecified", and "has value", than "null", "unspecified", "has value".

Comment: That said, "null" *does* have unclear semantics; I sympathize with this plight. Consider: what colour car does the customer prefer? "Unknown" and "no preference" are different. The first implies that there is a value, we just don't know what it is. The second implies that the customer has no preference. "What colour car is owned by the present king of France?" -- "unknown" is wrong, because that implies that there is such a value. "no color" seems wrong too. What we really want here is "the question doesn't make sense".  But all three of these things are conventionally represented by null.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I am with Eric. Does it matter whether a value is null by default or intentionally null. Are you going to handle these values differently?

Comment: I just thought of a fourth: "what colour does today's customer want us to paint the thing?" null could mean "don't paint it at all", or "we don't know yet", or "the customer doesn't care, but they want it painted, you choose", or "no customer has arrived yet today".  It's unfortunate that databases standardized the semantics of lifted nullable algebra in SQL without standardizing on the *meaning* of null in business terms.

Comment: @EricLippert: you can come up with any old predicate that has N referents (all possibly missing in action) and then demand we can represent any combination of value-and-missing for each of them, but null would still suffice -- you just need a whole box full of them. You're  really clamoring for a more expressive algebra, not a more expressive null.

Comment: @EricLippert: For example JSONs: {"name": null} and {} are different but when we deserialize them to DTO, the difference will not be preserved. I have designed such class to represent this.
Real use case may be PATCH-ing resources in RESTful API. If you want to allow patching only specified properties, such representation is very useful. You are able to distinguish between clearing a property and doing nothing to the property.

Comment: If you're open to using `double` instead of `decimal` you can use `Double.NaN` for the unspecified state

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments. It is unexpected that this question would receive this much attention. Eric Lippert dropping by to explain the design rational was definitely a surprise. I'll update the question with some more context for anyone that arrives in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Another non-ideal, but possibly workable, solution might be to use a Tuple<decimal?, bool>:

```
Tuple.Create<decimal?, bool>(null, true); //specified null
Tuple.Create<decimal?, bool>(null, false); //unspecified null
Tuple.Create<decimal?, bool>(1.0m, true);  //specified value
Tuple.Create<decimal?, bool>(1.0m, false); //??? insanity
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely, positively, do not want to use a custom class or enum, I would say your best option is to use `KeyValuePair<decimal, T>` where `T` is some representation of your 3 options (`string` for "unspecified"/"has value"/"null", `int` for -1/0/1, as you like)

I feel like this is pretty bad practice, but as per your specifications of no custom class, that's the best I've got.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to write your own implementation of such concept.

Minimal version may look like this:

```
sealed class Assignable<T>
{
    private readonly isAssigned;
    private readonly T value;

    public Assignable()
    {
    }

    public Assignable(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.isAssigned = true;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!isAssigned) throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsAssigned
    {
        get { return isAssigned; }
    }
}
```